# Identify Single wire communications protocol

Tags: communication, can, rs485, onewire

[image][image]
Hi guys
I  I have uploaded pictures from an oscilloscope.
 This is the signal that an indoor AC unit sends to the outdoor unit. It uses a single wire for communication and Seeing the PCB it looks like it is attached to a temperature  sensor through optical  isolation. Can someone suggest me the communication protocol it might be using? Also as far as I have looked CAN BUS can be used in a single wire mode. If this is CAN how should I start decoding it?

Comment: looks like two lots of asynchrinius serial, one above the line and one below the line, try feeding it to a UART.

Comment: how did you obtain this signal?  ...what is the make and model of the AC equipment?

Comment: The DC inverter Air conditioner I have has outdoor to indoor communication using a wire mentioned s on the connector and i used the Oscilloscope on neutral and S wire

Comment: Its manufactured by aux and K7 series

Comment: Speak to the suppliers of the equipment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to tell if this is a standard protocol or not from the information provided. It is not even certain how you measured the signal displayed so cannot even offer advice regarding the electrical characteristics of the signals.

You need to be aware that the manufacturer may very well be using some totally proprietary communications scheme.

If I had to investigate this I would do a teardown of the remote temperature sensor. (You may want to purchase a spare part for this purpose). Inside the temp sensor you may be able to observe some part numbers that would lead you to component data sheets. If the one wire communications is designed to be attached to a commercially available IC chip then the part data sheet will have details of how the communications works. On the other hand if the sensor is a custom part or the one wire is attached to some microcontroller you are going to be out of luck in finding a "standard protocol".